# Recital of mantra by initiated vs non initiated person

Tags: mantras, guru, initiation, deity

I have heard that mantras are taught in guru shishya relation,where the disciple receives **mantra Diksha(initiation)**.

If this is actually true,then **what are the differences between when a Dikshit person recites a mantra,versus when a non initiated normal individual recites the same mantra**?

Please answer with scriptural basis.

Comment: Non initiated persons are not qualified to recite scriptural mantras. There is no scripture which says otherwise. If a non initiate recite mantras then as per scriptures its not fruitful. You may want to see - (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20367/4732), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23240/4732), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29929/4732),

Comment: Is this applicable for mantras like Om Namah Shivaya,Om Namo Narayana,Shiva Gayatri Mantra?As someone may as well recite them out of just devotion ,and not for any special power...like a devotee.

Comment: Yes applicable. People do chant those and others out of devotion but the act is not sanctioned by scriptures.

Comment: @ Rickross Not sanctioned as in -not prohibited,but neither recommended,right?

Comment: No it's more than just "not recommended"

Comment: @Rickross So you mean it’s **prohibited** as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Talk 8, Talks with Ramana Maharshi**

> D: “Can anyone get any benefit by repeating sacred syllables (mantras)
> picked up casually?
>
> M.: “No. He must be competent and initiated in such mantras.” Maharshi
> illustrated this by the following story: A King visited his Premier in
> his residence. There he was told that the Premier was engaged in
> repetition of sacred syllables (japa). The King waited for him and, on
> meeting him, asked what the japa was. The Premier said that it was the
> holiest of all, Gayatri. The King desired to be initiated by the
> Premier. But the Premier confessed his inability to initiate him.
> Therefore the King learned it from someone else, and meeting the
> Minister later he repeated the Gayatri and wanted to know if it was
> right. The Minister said that the mantra was correct, but it was not
> proper for him to say it. When pressed for an explanation, the
> Minister called to a page close by and ordered him to take hold of the
> King. The order was not obeyed. The order was often repeated, and
> still not obeyed. The King flew into a rage and ordered the same man
> to hold the Minister, and it was immediately done. The Minister
> laughed and said that the incident was the explanation required by the
> King. “How?” asked the King. The Minister replied, “The order was the
> same and the executor also, but the authority was different. When I
> ordered, the effect was nil, whereas, when you ordered, there was
> immediate effect. Similarly with mantras.”

This is true for mantras that need to be initiated. However, for mantras like Ram, Krishn, there is no need for initiation. This [lecture (in Tamil)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbavoiwvXcU) cites the scriptural sanskrit source that says no initiation is required for reciting Ram, Ram. I will try to find the source text online.

Further, I believe that all the [stotras taken from the puranas](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/stotras/Stotra%20Kavacha(Shield%20of%20Prayers).html) can be recited by anyone.

Comment: What happens if the mantra is recited just in devotion,and not for any desired fruit as such?No one is harmed when a devotee recites a mantra of his /her ishta,right?

Comment: @Amethyst Sir, for tantric mantras, they may still be bad effects.

Comment: tantric?Would you explain?@GIRIBLR