# Who is the source of Deeksha?

Tags: mantras, guru, initiation, deity

[As discussed in this question’s comment section](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/47798/23958)

It is clear that the recital of (deity specific) mantras are not **”sanctioned”**(I don’t know what implications follow if someone does recite without Deeksha,I am quoting another user’s words) for uninitiated individuals.

So then,**who is the person who gave the original/initial Diksha**?The one whose disciples later passed down the Diksha to others,and **who Himself/Herself,did not require Deeksha**?

Comment: Obviously, it depends on the sect as to who's the Adi Guru (the Self): Shaiva & Shaktas = Shiva-Shakti, Vaishnavas = Vishnu (Krishna), et al..

Comment: @Vivikta So this is like asking ,”Who is Supreme?Lord Vishnu or Lord Shiva?”,right?

Comment: That's a futile debate: Verily know that it's the same Brahman donning different roles for different people (as per their "taste"). **ब्रह्मत्वे सृजते विश्वं स्थितौ पालयते पुनः ।
रुद्ररूपाय कल्पान्ते नमस्तुभ्यं त्रिमूर्तये** .

Comment: @This concept is fine by most sects ,I guess.I think the point of debate is who is the Brahman:Sri Krishna,Sadashiv,Devi,etc.Different Puranas say different things.

Comment: *"This concept is fine by most sects"* - Most definitely NOT.  *".I think the point of debate is who is the Brahman:Sri Krishna,Sadashiv,Devi,etc"* - that's why it's a futile exercise beacuse Puranas are sectarian and interpolated scriptures. Anything in the texts that speaks of regression or dicrimination must be rejected and things in their broadness of the Spirit are to be only accepted.

Comment: @Vivikta ,so you mean to say that sects don’t agree on the fact that Brahman dons different roles .?

Comment: @Vivikta What does non sectarian scripture like the Mahabharatha say in respect to my question?

Comment: I guess you want to know who is the first person who gets the mantra? Every mantra has a seer- see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17653/21353)

Comment: @Proxy This link doesn’t answer my question.For example,I have heard that Lord Shiva gave the Sanjeevani Mantra to Shukracharya.So here,Shukracharya is the one who receives the mantra Deeksha.Lord Shiva is the original *source* of the mantra ,Himself having not received Deeksha of the mantra from anyone else(I *presume* so).In the case of this mantra,I call Lord Shiva,”The Source”.I’d like to know Who is “The Source” for all other kinds of Deeksha,including mantra Deeksha.

Comment: Although Mahabharata is at large non-sectarian and an *itihAsa*, however, popular & major scholarly opinion categorizes both the *itihAsas* as primarily a Vaishanava focused texts, although both of them have eulogized all major deities, espcecially Shiva as a direct Brahman at several places (Mahabharata makes sure to do that many times). Further, you ask - *"I’d like to know Who is “The Source” for all other kinds of Deeksha, including mantra Deeksha."*, - that's equivalent to asking who's the "Original Brahman" - that is subject to sects and thus cannot be conculsively answered for everyone.

Comment: The history and tradition of receiving diksha mantra has been answered in a prior question. The origin of diksha mantras is the tantras. Different sects follow different traditions.  Try a search on this forum with diksha tantra

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda Will do Swamiji.